# Can Java based server with 100k thread survive

Tags: java, multithreading, load-balancing, serversocket

I want to host a application from home. 
My local machine: Core i7 2600 4 core,8 thread and 16GB memory 
Fiber: 100Mbps

My Target: 100k workerthread, each thread have its own while loop.

Will my machine survive. Code Sample:

```
serversocket obj_sock=new serversocket()
while(true){
new thread(new workerthread(obj_socket.accept());
}

class workerthread implements runnable{
      public workerthread(socket sock){
           rs=sock.getinputstream()
           ws=sock.getoutputstream()
       }
      public void(run){
        while(true){
         //do read stream, write stream
        }
      }
}
```

P.S.
I skipped exceptions in code.

Comment: I skipped many variable too, sorry

Comment: @MiniovaWeb We need more information

Comment: what kinda information you need, I will provide

Comment: It looks like this is something that you can just try by running it with these parameters.

Comment: yeah true, @ErwinBolwidt, I am thinking of typing a test app to generate that much socket request. but that test app will not resolve the real time problem when server go live. (that I think)

Comment: You really expect to have 100,000 **concurrent** users using your application, hosted at home, on a single machine? Just assuming that is possible, with 100Mbits/second, each of your 100,000 users would get at most 1000 bits/second, so 125 bytes per second. I doubt those 100,000 users keep using the app with such a bandwidth.

Comment: Not to mention that just for the stack of each thread, assuming it's 500KB, you would already need 50 GB of memory.

Comment: @JB Nizet, thats also correct, before that we need to handle 100K connection without data exchange between socket

Comment: I will inform you and share simple server and test client code

Answer (score 2):

The default thread stack size on my 64-bit Java 8 is 1M. That means that 100,000 threads will need 100G of RAM to work with. That is tunable, and you could probably get under 16G, but software would require more testing with a constrained stack.

It seems like operating systems will let you create that many threads.

I would strongly suggest looking into an event-driven (i.e. non-blocking) protocol framework like [Netty](http://netty.io/) or [Apache MINA](https://mina.apache.org/) to implement your server.

Comment: No third party api or SDK, Just Java only, I am coding a test client, Will post output today or tomm